# How to pass the values to the highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have following code, trying to get "this.y" outside highcharts function for setting different tooltip text for data. Please help me out how to pass y access values?

```
var series = [];
var myData = {
    'color': 'url(#defaultYou)',
    'name': 'Me',
    'data': [],
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: 'Your current Salary in USD this.y',
        footerFormat: '',
    }
};

var maleData = {
    showInLegend: false,
    'color': 'url(#defaultMale)',
    'name': 'Male',
    'data': [],
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: 'Income this.y <br> Experience 3 Year(s)',
        footerFormat: '',
    }
};

var femaleData = {
    showInLegend: false,
    'color': 'url(#defaultFemale)',
    'name': 'Female',
    'data': [],
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: 'Income this.y <br> Experience 3 Year(s)',
        footerFormat: '',
    }
};

series = [maleData, femaleData, myData];

drawChart(series, 'My Chart Title');

function drawChart(series, chartTitle) {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            spacingBottom: 0,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                }
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: chartTitle,
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
                color: '#333333',
                fontSize: '18px',
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 20,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickWidth: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        series: series

    });

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Highcharts's docs:

> **pointFormat:** 
>   StringSince 2.2 The HTML of the point's line in the
>   tooltip. **Variables are enclosed by curly brackets**.....

Long story short, instead of using `this.y` you should use `{point.y}`.
http://jsfiddle.net/kadoshms/qgx28yyp/